# Giving levels under a numeric value

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to convert some numeric values into factors. The conversion would depend on the values of the numeric inputs.

For example, let's say we have a data frame called `ex` and a conversion one called `tmp`. If the p-value if inferior to a certain limit, the corresponding factor would be returned.

```
ex <- data.frame(pval = c(0.002, 0.3, 0.02, 0.00005, 0.09))
tmp <- data.frame(sign = c("***", "**", "*", "+", "ns"), lim = c(.001, .01, .05, .1, 1))
```

For every `pval` value in `ex`, I would like to get the correct `sign` in `tmp` but I'm not sure how to do this without using a succession of `ifelse`.

Desired output:

```
data.frame(pval = c(0.002, 0.3, 0.02, 0.00005, 0.09),
                  res = c("**", "ns", "*", "***", "+"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a fairly obscure base R function that is specifically designed for such purposes, `symnum`:

```
ex$cond <- symnum(ex$pval, symbols=c("***", "**", "*", "+", "ns"),
                  cutpoints=c(0, .001, .01, .05, .1, 1.1))
```

which returns

```
ex
   pval cond
1 2e-03   **
2 3e-01   ns
3 2e-02    *
4 5e-05  ***
5 9e-02    +
```

---

Also, the base R function`cut` will work perfectly fine here.

```
ex$cond <- cut(ex$pval, labels=c("***", "**", "*", "+", "ns"),
               breaks=c(0, .001, .01, .05, .1, 1.1))

ex
   pval cond
1 2e-03   **
2 3e-01   ns
3 2e-02    *
4 5e-05  ***
5 9e-02    +
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rolling join from `data.table`:

```
setDT(ex, key="pval")
setDT(tmp, key="lim")

tmp[ex, roll=-Inf]
   sign     lim
1:  *** 0.00005
2:   ** 0.00200
3:    * 0.02000
4:    + 0.09000
5:   ns 0.30000
```